# Jquery syntax for javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following code written in normal js:-

```
var trCat = document.getElementById('trCat');
var tr_1 = document.createElement('tr');
tr_1.id = 'trCat_'+val;
tr_1.style.width = '100%';    
trCat.parentNode.insertBefore( tr_1 , trCat );
tr_1.attachEvent('onclick' , function() {
    DeleteRow(val)
});
```

How Can i replicate the above code in JQUERY? Any Suggestions are most welcome..

Comment: I suggest you start bei having a look at the jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('<tr />')
  .attr('id', 'trCat_'+val)
  .css('width', '100%')
  .click(function() {
    DeleteRow(val);
  }).insertBefore($('#trCat').parent());
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is, of course, to learn jQuery. That way you can just DIY next time. If you don't have enough time for that, here's the answer:

```
var trCat = $('#trCat');
var tr_1 = $('<tr></tr>')
    .attr('id', 'trCat_' + val)
    .css('width', '100%')
    .click(function() {DeleteRow($val);});
trCat.before(tr_1);
```

Comment: Both var tr_1 = $('<tr></tr>')
and var tr_1 = $('<tr />')
are not working.Even,var trCat = $('#trCat'); is not working.

Comment: @Romit: And what does *not working* mean?

Comment: Means something wrong in syntax..